# web scraping with python scrapy library (python 3)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, screen-scraping

I want scraping a persian web with scrapy lib and store data in a csv file.

But in gitbash show this:

```
"{'title': '\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646: \u0641\u0648\u0644\u0627\u062f \u0648 \u0646\u06a9\u0648\u0646\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0637\u0634 \u0645\u0648\u0641\u0642\u06cc\u062a \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0646\u062f', 'author': '\n                  \u062f\u0631\u0648\u0627\u0632\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0646 \u062c\u062f\u06cc\u062f \u062a\u06cc\u0645 \u0641\u0648\u0644\u0627\u062f \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u062f\u0648\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0627 \u0648\u06cc\u0698\u06af\u06cc \u0647\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u062c\u0648\u0627\u062f \u0646\u06a9\u0648\u0646\u0627\u0645 \u0633\u0631\u0627\u063a \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f\u060c \u0633\u0631\u062e\u067e\u0648\u0634\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0647\u0648\u0627\u0632 \u0641\u0635\u0644\u06cc \u0645\u0648\u0641\u0642 \u062f\u0631 \u067e\u06cc\u0634 \u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u0646\u062f.\n                '}"
```

And in my csv file its like this:

```
"Ù¾ÛŒØ§Ù… Ø®Ø¯Ø§Ø­Ø§ÙØ¸ÛŒ Ø§ÛŒØ³Ù…Ø§ Ø¨Ø±Ø§ÛŒ Ù‡ÙˆØ§Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø§Ù† Ø§Ø³ØªÙ‚Ù„Ø§Ù„"
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should try with python3 first if you're using python 2.

Comment: i use python3 !

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it's possible that the file is alright (stored with UTF-8), but you're using a Windows application like Excel to view the file, which interprets the data with another encoding (eg. Latin-1), which results in the mojibake you see. Check if you can select UTF-8 encoding when importing the csv.

Comment: In any case, in order to be helped, you need to show some code (best read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), not just the output. There's no way to tell what is going wrong without knowing what you're doing in the first place. Also, you should probably show what you want the output to look like.